# Linux install on PowerEdge 2950 hangs with Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok

Tags: linux, dell-poweredge

First off, this is not an issue with EDD, but what ever comes next. If I include `edd=off` it just hangs without displaying anything after GRUB.

- I've attempted to install current versions of Arch, Debian & Ubuntu with the same result.
- The USB disk works fine elsewhere.
- I've tried adding `intel_pstate=no_hwp`  to no avail
- I've tried dozens of combos of disabling acpi, apic, getting acpi_osi=Linux and everything else related to ACPI to no avail.
- And reeeaallly annoyingly, setting loglevel=7 (or 8 or anything else) doesn't give anymore info.

Other reading indicated it might have to do with the RAID setup. Presently there is a single disk, configured (and initialized) as RAID 0.

I'm pretty much at a loss of where to go from here, even just getting more logging would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Is your firmware up to date?

Comment: Probably not, when I received it I was told it had a firmware for fan speed control,besides can it be updated w/o Windows installed?

Comment: It's a server, (albeit an ancient one) you can do pretty much anything you need to do to manage it without an operating system installed. Though, remember it _is_ ancient and may have trouble running modern operating systems.

Comment: So my options seem JET ENGINE fans or matching ancient distro.

Comment: Well, this is a server.